# How to insert symbol when encountering duplicates in a string

Tags: javascript

Lets assume that I have this string: `aabbc` and between every character which is not equal to the prior character I want to insert a symbol.

Which would result in the following string: `aa$bb$c`

How can this be achived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in following steps:

- You can convert string to array using Spread Operator
- Then use `map()` on it
- Inside `map()` check if the element on next to current is not same as current letter then add `$` at its end.
- Use `join()` to make array a string.
- Remove the last `$` using `slice()` which is extra.

```js
let str = 'aabbc';
let res = [...str].map((x,i,arr) => arr[i+1] !== arr[i] ? x + '$' : x).join('').slice(0,-1)
console.log(res)
```

You can also use RegExp and `match()`

```js
let str = 'aabbc';
let res = str.match(/(.)(\1*)/g).join('$')
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with a single [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
input.replace(/(.)(?!\1)(?=.)/g, "$1$$")
```

Explanation of the pattern:

- `.` - matches any single character (except newline); let's call this character X.
- `(.)` - capturing subpattern; captures X so that it can be referenced in the replacement string (explained below).
- `\1` - backreference; matches another character identical to X.
- `(?!\1)` - negative look-ahead; matches only if the X matched so far, is *not* followed by another X.
- `(?=.)` - positive look-ahead; matches only if the X matched so far, is followed by any other character; in other words, asserts that the line does not end here. Can be omitted if you don't mind having a trailing `$` appended.

Explanation of the replacement string:

- `$1` - the X captured by the first capturing subpattern (see above).
- `$$` - a single `$`.

Example:

```js
var input = "aabbc";
var out = input.replace(/(.)(?!\1)(?=.)/g, "$1$$");
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to do:

```
var charArray = myString.split(''); //this should split the string in an array of the characters. ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]
var newString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length -1; i++) { //I do length -1 so to not cause an IndexOutOfBoundException at charArrayi+1]
    if (charArray[i] === charArray[i+1]) {
        newString += charArray[i] + charArray[i+1] + "$";
    }
}
```

Something like that maybe?
I haven't actually tested this, I just typed it in here.
But in my head this feels right. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = 'aabbc';

let last = '';
let str = '';
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i += 1) {
 str += a[i];
 if (last === a[i]) {
  str += '$';
 }

 last = a[i];
}

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using simple `for` loop as mentioned below:

```js
var string = "aabbc";
var checkChar = "";
for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
  checkChar += string.charAt(i);
  if (string.charAt(i - 1) === string.charAt(i)){
      checkChar += "$";
  }  
}
console.log(checkChar)
```